# jQuery class is statically sharing an object across class instances

Tags: jquery, oop

A while ago I needed to create an object orientated class using jQuery. I turned to use [John Resig's](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) fine Class solution.

Hit an issue with it. When I define a global options object, it seems to me that the latter is shared amongst classes. I have confirmed that by printing various console.log's after modifying the object in one class only. The code looks like this:

```
var MyClass = Class.extend({
    defaults : {
        distance : 10,
        speed : 20
    },
    options : null,

    init : function(options) {
        this.options = $.extend(this.defaults, options);
    },

    ...
});
```

I need a global hash or array so that i can easily pass optional settings to the class. Any way of doing it this way? I might have to resort to manual setters to the class if nothing works.

I am not too sure either why the options object is being statically shared across different class objects instantiated with the 'new' keyword.

Comment: I would like to help you, but am not exactly clear on the question. Could you should the code where you are using the class?

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong here, but try taking the "var" off of "var MyClass".  Doing so will create "MyClass" in the window namespace, which in essence makes it global.

---

UPDATE

Is this what you need?

```
var myObject = function() {
    var defaults = {
                      speed: 20,
                      distance: 10
    };
    var options = null;
    return {
        init: function() { ... },
        setSpeed: function(speed) { this.defaults['speed'] = speed; },
        // etc
    }

}
```

and then call it such as:

```
myObject.init();
```

or

```
myObject.setSpeed(100);
```

perhaps i dont understand the problem correctly and i should just stfu

p.s - the above code is straight from memory and not tested

Comment: I was a bit sceptical from your reply (since I didn't understand how making my class global will change the access rights of an internal variable to it), but indeed there was a change, and some values in my options array were unique. However, some other values have been carried over from the first class's internal values.

Comment: hady - javascript is actually a classless language.  Perhaps, re-wording the problem and asking yourself the problem again may help.  I just re-read your question and perhaps I misunderstood...

Answer (score 0):

They are indeed sharing the **options** value, but that's because you assigned a *modifed* **this.defaults** and not a distinct object.  From the [jQuery.extend() docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.extend#deeptargetobject1objectN):

> Keep in mind that the target object
>   will be modified, and will be returned
>   from extend().

You can fix it by extending an empty object with the defaults and then options:

```
    this.options = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
```